# Java library can't reference classes in dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I'm trying to build an annotation processor for an Android SDK, which is distributed as an AAR. This annotation processor should not be distributed with the SDK so I am building it as a separate JAR, in a separate project.

When creating the Java library project, I am unable to import classes (annotations in this case) from the SDK AAR. I've added the AAR as a dependency and verified that it is resolving it correctly (it comes from a custom Maven repository) during the build:

[image] The AAR in question is obbsdk.aar

I've opened up the archive and ensured that the classes I am referencing are in the AAR that is being resolved. I'm not sure what else I should look at since it seems to me that the things to verify are that the classes are there and the AAR is referenced.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried importing the aar in this way `implementation('com.yoursdk:1.0.0@aar') { transitive = true }` to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @MatPag I had not but it does not make a difference unfortunately

Comment: It's not so clear what you have done, my suggestion is to check how other annotation processors have been constructed and check their build.gradle files and build scripts. Two big projects which are using annotation processor extensively are [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/java/dagger/internal/codegen) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/annotation/compiler/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/annotation/compiler)

Comment: @MatPag Thanks for the suggestion I've been slowly looking through Dagger.

Comment: Glide has an easier implementation of the compiler, check it first

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fundamental issue I was running into was having a 'java-library' project depend on an 'com.android.library' project. I fixed the issue by moving the functionality I need to share out of the SDK into a separate java library and then having both libraries use that as a dependency.